# Instantiating a class produces ReflectionTypeLoadException at Assembly.GetTypes()

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, asp.net-web-api, telerik-reporting

I discovered that after my application generates Telerik report

```
var result = new ReportProcessor().RenderReport("PDF", new InstanceReportSource { ReportDocument = new MyTelerikReport(data) }, null);
var stream = new MemoryStream(result.DocumentBytes);

return CreateHttpFileResponse("MyReport.pdf", stream, "application/pdf");
```

I am not able to get all types within `CurrentDomain`

```
var typesWithAttribute = (from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                          from t in a.GetTypes() //error appears here
                          //some filtering logic
                          select t).ToList();
```

I am getting error

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information.

LoaderExceptions:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.  The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

After some investigation I found that assembly that fails to load: `Telerik.Reporting.OpenXmlRendering, Version=8.0.14.311, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be` and that assembly doesn't exists in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` before I generate report (I assume that assembly loaded dynamically by `Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.0.14.311, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be`).

I could filter out that assembly as I don't need any types from that but I am a bit worried about fact of having assemblies in domain that cannot be loaded - seems a bit wrong to me.

Could someone explain what there happens? Is it my issue or that is fault of 3rd party library that doesn't load all required assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the assembly but the `Type` coming from a dependent assembly that has not been loaded.

> If the GetTypes method is called on an assembly and a type in that assembly is dependent on a type in an assembly that has not been loaded (for example, if it derives from a type in the second assembly), a ReflectionTypeLoadException is thrown.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx